# How not to display last grid line in a 3D.js barchart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, bar-chart, gridlines

I have two horizontal barcharts in a page, drawn with D3.js.
First barchart values go from 0 to 99 (%), second barchart values from 0 to 100 (%).

I displayed the first barchart with an x-axis longer than the max value (ex: length corresponding to 110) with ticks and labels every 10 up to 100, and a vertical grid every 10 up to 100 as well (value 110 is excluded from visualization).
I'm trying to do the same for the second barchart, but in this case the last tick and the last gridline corresponding to 110 are always displayed. In figure the first and second chart respectively.

- horizontal barchart with x-axis value up to 100
  [image]
- horizontal barchart with x-axis value up to 110
  [image]

Here is the code to display axis and grid for the first barchart:

```
function make_x1_gridlines() {      
        return d3.axisBottom(x1)
            .ticks(10)
    }

x1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })+10]);
gw1.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")  
        .call(make_x1_gridlines()
            .tickSize(height1)
            .tickFormat("")
            .tickSizeOuter(0)); //hide last grid line
    gw1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height1 + ")")  
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x1)
                .tickSizeOuter(0))
            .append("text")
                .attr("font-size", "1rem")
                .attr("y", 120)
                .attr("x", 440)
                .attr("dy", "-5rem")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Percentage");                
    gw1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y1)
                .tickSizeOuter(0));
```

The code for the second barchart is the same, but the index that is 2 instead of 1.
I think the problem is in the range value up to 100 in the second barchart, cause if I change values 100 with 99, the code works and the second chart is displayed correctly, but I can find the way not to display last tick and grid-line.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you know the tick values you want, can you try using [d3-axis_tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues)? That'd be helpful. Here's an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/2f0f6176a0a2473a560d).

Comment: or you can run your domain up to 109.99

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions work. I prefer the second one because it's more general